# Ansible iterate over hosts in inventory group set by variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have the next snippet in my role template:

```
upstream portal {
 {% set nodes = groups["my_dev_cluster"] %}
 {% for node in nodes %}
 ...do something with nodes...
 {% endfor %}
}
```

And it works well.

But when I try to parametrize inventory group name like this:

```
upstream portal {
 {% set nodes = groups["{{cluster_name}}"] %}
 {% for node in nodes %}
 ...do something with nodes...
 {% endfor %}
}
```

I get an exception like:

```
 FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute '{{cluster_name}}'"}
```

Here, **cluster_name** - is a simple string variable defined in defaults section.

Is it possible to parametrize it at all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `{{...}}` because you're already inside a jinja context (in this case, the `{% set ... %}` block.  Just write:

```
{% set nodes = groups[cluster_name] %}
```