# Ansible Playbook - Import Playbook pass Host Name for each in Group - Rescursive Loop detected

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, roles

please excuse my question firstly. I have searched and spent time looking at [How to iterate over inventory group in ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080226/how-to-iterate-over-inventory-group-in-ansible) and [Ansible iterate over hosts in inventory group set by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698210/ansible-iterate-over-hosts-in-inventory-group-set-by-variable) style questions.

So will try keep question simple.

Inventory Looks like: ( this is all sample adapted to explain a little better .. )

```
[GroupA]
host1 country=USA
host2 country=USA
host3 country=UK
```

So I want to pass the Group through only without the hosts , so that the playbook is executed across each host. However as part of the playbook , firstly i need to run a script on a different server ( depending on the country ) and pass the hostname to that script.

In my testing , I discovered "inventory_hostname" so that even if i didnt pass the host and I passed the Group , I could put the hostname into a variable.

When i put it all together and started with import_playbook ( because this playbook is for a different server ) , I saw :

```
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ runninghost }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ v_host_name }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: recursive loop detected in template string: {{ v_host_name }}
```

I have a playbook where i have some conditionals based on the "country"

```
- hosts: "{{ v_world }}"

   vars:
    v_world: "{{ v_world }}"
    hostvalue : "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

 - import_playbook: country-stuff-USA.yml
   vars:
    v_host_name: "{{ hostvalue }}"
   when: hostvars[groups[v_world][0]]['country'] == "USA"

 - import_playbook: country-stuff-UK.yml
   vars:
    v_host_name: "{{ hostvalue }}"
   when: hostvars[groups[v_world][0]]['country']  == "UK"


country-stuff-USA.yml

---
 - hosts: "world-server-usa.world"
   vars:
     runninghost: "{{ v_host_name }}"

   roles:
   - role: world_peace-usa
     poll: 0
     vars:
      hostvalue: "{{ runninghost }}"

country-stuff-UK.yml

---
 - hosts: "world-server-usa.world"
   vars:
     runninghost: "{{ v_host_name }}"

   roles:
   - role: world_peace-uk
     poll: 0
     vars:
      hostvalue: "{{ runninghost }}"      

world_peace-uk ( main.yml )

- name: world_peace-uk
  shell: ksh /mountA/scriptuk.sh -host={{hostvalue}} 

world_peace-uk ( main.yml )

- name: world_peace-usa
  shell: ksh /mountA/scriptusa.sh -host={{hostvalue}}
```

Any thoughts ? I am sure I am doing something very wrong with this combination.. but i couldnt think of a better way to use the Groups , but to pass the hostname onto a script on a different box.

Many Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating your issue, you should use [delegation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) whenever you need to perform a task on a different host then the ones specified in the play. For example:

```
---

- hosts: running_hosts

  tasks:
  - name: tasks to execute on another host
    module: ...
    delegate_to: other_host

  - name: tasks to execute on the running host
    module: ...
```

Regarding the error you are getting, it's because `v_world` is referencing itself in the statement `v_world: "{{ v_world }}"`

Comment: Thank you so much for response. I guessed that I was over-complicating , I am literally approaching this like "Lego" Blocks based on my lack of experience. Will try this out and let you know.